# How to select only the last timestamp of each hour in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to **extract hourly** reports of a database **for each process**, but it has entries every second. 
 
Since this is too much data to work with, I would like to get only the latest update of each hour. I am not an expert in SQL and tried already some "simple" solutions which did not work for me.

I hope you can help me out here.

```
SELECT
    report_id, start_date_local, process,
    productivity, dw_last_updated
    
FROM table_name

WHERE start_date_local > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
    
ORDER BY dw_last_updated, ppr_report_id desc
```

| report_id | start_date_local | process | productivity | dw_last_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2021-01-14 00:00:00.0 | x | 0.0551 | 2021-02-16 06:16:19.0 |
| 0002 | 2021-01-14 00:00:00.0 | y | 0.0333 | 2021-02-16 06:16:19.0 |
| 0003 | 2021-01-14 00:00:00.0 | z | 0.0164 | 2021-02-16 06:16:19.0 |
| 0004 | 2021-01-14 00:00:00.0 | x | 0.0850 | 2021-02-16 06:23:21.0 |
| 0005 | 2021-01-14 00:00:00.0 | y | 0.0238 | 2021-02-16 06:17:27.0 |
| 0006 | 2021-01-14 00:00:00.0 | z | 0.0542 | 2021-02-16 06:44:10.0 |

So in this example I would like to get only report_id = 0004, 0005, 0006

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: I don't use redshift but if you have window function support you need something like this [Get top 1 row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group/14346780)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to group entries by process and get the max timestamp. So you need to put your query in GROUP BY clause:

manual:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

```
SELECT process,
       report_id,
       start_date_local,

       productivity,
       max(dw_last_updated) last_updated

FROM table_name

WHERE start_date_local > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())

GROUP BY process
```

Comment: I think "max(dw_last_updated)" is giving me the the latest timestamp based on seconds. I've got the isssue that I need the hourly reports only. Seconds are not relevant for me. But since the column is timestamp without zone, I can not even change the format or convert it without the seconds. So there is no workaround as far I can see.